# Error BEA-380001 OSB Proxy response

Tags: web-services, replace, proxy, osb

I trying to use the replace element into proxy service to mapping the request and response of sap web service and test the web service in the SoapUI the result is the next

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>BEA-380001: Internal Server Error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
               <con:errorCode>BEA-380001</con:errorCode>
               <con:reason>Internal Server Error</con:reason>
               <con:location>
                  <con:node>RouteNode1</con:node>
                  <con:path>response-pipeline</con:path>
               </con:location>
            </con:fault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tested the web service sap and it works, I've tried the default proxy and it works, I think that what is failing the response and conversion in xquery. 
I've tried several configurations and nothing has worked ... I leave the images of the initial settings to give me any idea what might be going

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run the proxy through Test console and check the trace?

Comment: I have got the same issue. Also when using the OSB test console. Would be a huge help if someone has any clue.

Comment: Without looking at the xquery the answer can not be given.

Answer (score 1):

As the error doesn't seem to have any clear answer, all I can do is give some tips to help debugging. Please forgive me if you already tried it all.

1) Log $body contents after the request Replace and before the response Replace. You can use the Report component for this. The log/report will be available at http://host:7101/em console. Them you can validate both XMLs against the wsdl using some online tool or SOAPUI.

2) You can call the Business Service at the test console using the transformed request to see if any errors or invalid response come from there.

3) In the XQuery editor you have the option to test both transformations, you can use the logged request and response to test if they work properly.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. However, in my case it was a data(casing) issue which is case sensitive. Why don't you change your data to lowercase as `false` instead of `False`?